# Como arrumar a hora da função localtime() em C

Tags: c, data, time

Estou tendo uma dúvida em relação à função `localtime()`. Quando eu dou um `printf` na variável `local` o horário sai com 3 horas de diferença. O dia o mês e o ano estão corretos, mas a hora não. Eu estou usando o GDBonline para rodar o programa.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

int main()
{
    time_t t;
    struct tm *local;
    t=time(NULL);
    local=localtime(&t);
    printf("%s", asctime(local));
    
    return 0;
}
```

[image: GDBonline Output]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Funções como `localtime` usam o *timezone* (fuso horário) que está configurado no ambiente no qual o código roda.

Você pode alterar o timezone mudando o valor da [variável de ambiente `TZ`](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/TZ-Variable.html), usando a [função `setenv`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/setenv.3.html).

Exemplo:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int main() {
    time_t t = time(NULL);

    // usando o timezone atual (valor que a variável TZ tem atualmente)
    printf("%-20s - %s", getenv("TZ"), asctime(localtime(&t)));

    // mudando para diferentes timezones
    char *timezones[] = {"Europe/London", "America/Los_Angeles", "Pacific/Apia", "Asia/Tokyo", "America/Sao_Paulo", "UTC"};
    size_t len = sizeof timezones / sizeof timezones[0];
    for (size_t i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        setenv("TZ", timezones[i], 1);
        printf("%-20s - %s", timezones[i], asctime(localtime(&t)));
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Primeiro eu usei o valor atual da variável `TZ` (se ela não estiver setada, será usado o timezone que estiver configurado no ambiente no qual o código roda). Testando no [OnlineGDB](https://www.onlinegdb.com/3sTlqMdJU), a saída foi:

```
(null)               - Fri Mar 25 12:17:21 2022
Europe/London        - Fri Mar 25 12:17:21 2022
America/Los_Angeles  - Fri Mar 25 05:17:21 2022
Pacific/Apia         - Sat Mar 26 02:17:21 2022
Asia/Tokyo           - Fri Mar 25 21:17:21 2022
America/Sao_Paulo    - Fri Mar 25 09:17:21 2022
UTC                  - Fri Mar 25 12:17:21 2022
```

Repare que na primeira linha a variável `TZ` não está setada (`getenv` retornou `null`), por isso ele usou o timezone *default* do ambiente. Já nas linhas seguintes, depois de setar o timezone com `setenv`, a data e hora passam a respeitar o respectivo fuso - repare que para `Pacific/Apia` (nas [ilhas Samoa](https://goo.gl/maps/eR2BWzDUfufvE54p8)) já é dia 26, inclusive.

Então o que acontece é que o ambiente no qual o OnlineGDB roda o código está com algum fuso horário diferente do que você espera, daí a diferença. Olhando o resultado acima, podemos inferir que ele usa [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time), e de fato podemos conferir isso com o código abaixo:

```c
struct tm lt = {0};
localtime_r(&t, &lt);
printf("timezone atual= '%s'.\n", lt.tm_zone);
```

Rodando no OnlineGDB, o timezone atual é "UTC". Porém, rodando na minha máquina, a primeira linha mostrou o horário "09:17:21", pois meu ambiente está usando o Horário de Brasília (na verdade, o resultado do "timezone atual" foi `-03` - ou seja, 3 horas atrás do UTC).

---

Resumindo, você precisa setar o timezone adequado (e qual usar vai depender do que exatamente você precisa). Se não quiser usar `setenv`, você pode setar a variável `TZ` na linha de comando. Por exemplo, em um shell Linux bastaria digitar algo como:

```
TZ=America/Sao_Paulo seu_programa
```

Que o programa executa usando o timezone indicado pela variável `TZ` (aí o programa não precisa usar `setenv`). Mas se quer que o programa sempre use algum timezone específico, aí seria mais interessante usar `setenv` mesmo.

Os nomes como `America/Sao_Paulo` são definidos pela [IANA](https://www.iana.org/time-zones), mas a variável `TZ` [também aceita outros formatos](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/TZ-Variable.html).

Comment: Valeu, cara. Muito obrigado mesmo!